# Bean validation not working?

Tags: java, validation, jakarta-ee, jboss, bean-validation

I have a `services` module, with `ClientRequest` class as

```
public class ClientRequest {
    @NotNull(message = "email can not be empty")
    private String email;
    @NotNull(message = "userExternalId can not be empty")
    private String userExternalId;
    @NotNull(message = "password can not be empty")
    private String password;


    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public ClientRequest() {
        // used by jax-rs
    }
```

**services/pom.xml** has

```
<properties>
    <validation-api.version>1.1.0.Final</validation-api.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I have `integration` module for writing integration tests.
**integration/pom.xml** looks like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and I my test looks like

```
    @Test
    public void testRegisterClientInValid() throws IOException {
        final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        final Invocation.Builder request = client.target("http://localhost:9090/application/oauth/register").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("email", "integrationTest@gmail.com");
        final Response response = request.post(Entity.entity(parameters, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.SC_OK, response.getStatus());

        final JsonNode jsonReply = getObjectMapper().readTree(response.readEntity(String.class));
        System.out.println(jsonReply);
    }
```

Since I am expecting it to fails with `bean validation`, I see what logs has to say.

I see

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3587) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:103) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:421) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
```

Which means `bean validation` passed and error is at database layer because database expects a `not null` value

**Question**
Why is bean validation not working, what is that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @mad_fox, sorry I do not remember this

Answer (score 0):

According to your example you are using Hibernate Validator 4.0.2.GA together with Bean  Validation 1.1.0.Final. That is not going to work. To use Bean Validation 1.1 you will need Hibernate Validator 5.x (5.1.2.Final being the latest). I would expect that your example is not even bootstrapping properly or eat least that there are some warnings in the logs.

Comment: I tried it with `5.1.2.Final` but error is still the same

Comment: @daydreamer I have the similar issue. Have you figured it out?

Comment: nope. and this is pretty old issue, I do not remember